# Go's built-in range on a sub-slice of an array has incongruent behavior

Tags: arrays, go, range, slice

Why can't we use the built `range` to dictate the lower-end of given array's index, but we can specify the index's upper range?

Given a slice of int:

```
array := []int{4, 76, -29, 3, 9, 223, 0, -3, -44, 76, 3, 98, 62, 144}
```

I want to range over the slice, excluding the first two elements.

I can do this with a for-loop:

```
for i := 2; i < len(array); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", array[i])
    }
```

But can't with the built-in `range`:

```
for i := range array[2:] {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", array[i])
    }
```

Strangely enough, i **can** exclude elements on the upper-range, like so:

```
for i := range array[:5] {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", array[i])
    }
```

Run it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kjAkKf5ipsg)

Why is this?

Comment: Your code does not contain any array. Maybe redoing the Tour of Go to refresh your memory about slices and arrays and how for loops work might be a good idea.

Comment: i just use the term array and slice interchangeably and probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression array[2:] evaluates to new slice value. The problem is that the application assumes that the elements in the new slice have the same index as the corresponding element in   `array`.

Here are a couple of approaches for addressing the problem.

Use the range value:

```
for _, v := range array[2:] {
   fmt.Printf("%d ", v)
}
```

Index into the new slice:

```
s := array[2:]
for i := ranges s {
   fmt.Printf("%d ", s[i])
}
```

When slicing from the end as in `array[:5]`, the elements in the new slice have the same index as the corresponding elements in `array`.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, you are simply looking at the wrong slice.

The expression `array[2:]` is a new slice that starts from the 2'nd element of the `array`. The 0'th element of that slice is the 2nd element of the original slice. Do this, and you'll see:

```
for i,value := range array[2:] {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", value)
}
```

The values for `i` range from 0 to len(array)-2.